# How to fix warning "Format specifies type 'void *' but the argument has type 'char' warning"

Tags: c, pointers, printf, c-strings, conversion-specifier

I am getting the output that I want but can't figure out how to get rid of these warnings. Any help is appreciated.

**Warnings:**

1. Format specifies type 'void *' but the argument has type 'char' [-Wformat]
   printf("\nThe pointer variable's value is %p\n", *myString);
2. "Format specifies type 'void *' but the argument has type 'char' [-Wformat]
   printf("%p\n", myString[x]);

   ```
    #include <stdio.h>
    #include <stdlib.h>

    int main() {

      char *myString = "Daniel";
      int x;

      printf("\nThe pointer variable's value is %p\n", *myString);
      printf("\nThe pointer variable points to %s\n", myString);
      printf("\nThe memory location for each character are: \n");


      for (x = 0;x < 7;x++){
       printf("%p\n", myString[x]);
      }

    return 0;
    }
   ```

**Ouput:**

```
     The pointer variable's value is 0x44

     The pointer variable points to Daniel

     The memory location for each character are: 
     0x44
     0x61
     0x6e
     0x69
     0x65
     0x6c
     (nil)
```

Comment: `*myString` and `myString[x]` are of type `char`, but you print them with `%p` which is for pointers. You probably want to replace them with `myString` and `&myString[x]` (or to be even stricter -  `(void*)myString` and `(void*)&myString[x]`)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For starters these calls

```
printf("\nThe pointer variable's value is %p\n", *myString);
```

and

```
printf("%p\n", myString[x]);
```

do not make a sense because you are trying to use a value of a character as a pointer value.

As for the other warning then just cast pointers to the type `void *`. For example

```
printf("\nThe pointer variable's value is %p\n", ( void * )myString);
printf("\nThe pointer variable points to %s\n", myString);
printf("\nThe memory location for each character are: \n");


for (x = 0;x < 7;x++){
 printf("%p\n", ( void * )( myString + x ));
}
```